# How can I fix the discrepancy between root directories when building an Electron.js project?

Tags: electron

When running my Electron project normally, like `electron ./artist-test-kit-main.js`, everything works fine. When I build the project into an executable, attempts to load files start failing, like: `Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'asset-editor\data.json'` So I ran a test to see if there's a difference in the root directory between the normal (`electron ./artist-test-kit-main.js`) execution and the .exe's.

Within `index.js` (launched by `index.html`, launched by `artist-test-kit-main.js` which is a standard electron.js initiator file):

```
console.log(fs.readdirSync('./'))
```

In the `.exe`, this outputs:

[image]

In the normal dev execution (`electron ./artist-test-kit-main.js`), this outputs:

[image]

This usual root directory of the project is, after being packaged, stored in the `resources` directory seen in the `.exe` execution root directory. So now all my file reads seem to be broken because of this discrepancy in root directories.

How can I solve this?

My `package.json` shows the build arguments used:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "artist-test-kit-main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "start-artist": "electron ./artist-test-kit-main.js",
    "build": "electron-packager ./ game --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite=true",
    "build-art": "electron-packager ./ asset-editor --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite=true"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^15.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TLDR

Use `__dirname` instead of `.`

#### Explanation

`.` refers to the current working directory (cwd), which is the directory in which the node process was started.

For an unpackaged app, this is usually the root folder of your project, producing the expected results. For a packaged app, the cwd will likely be where the Electron executable is stored. The app's contents (what was previously the root folder) are put inside `resources/app` or `resources/app.asar` relative to the executable.

The way to unify the packaged and unpackaged scenarios is to use `__dirname`, which contains the directory of the currently running Node script. This way, it will be the same as using `.` in an unpackaged app, but will return the path with `resources/app` in the packaged scenario, as that is then the location of the currently running Node script.

This is why you'll often see people using something like `` `file://${__dirname}/assets/index.html` `` to address files in Electron.

#### Side note

If you use `require('./file.js')`, the path is evaluated relative to the location of the calling script and will work as if you had used `__dirname`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out of your day to help.

Comment: Saved me as well (mine was a LimeLM related path issue)